# Por que as tabelas criadas no hibernate são excluídas depois de parar o servidor?

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu rodo meu site e ele gera as tabelas no banco de dados. Eu até consigo fazer o cadastro no banco de dados pelo site e seu der um *select* ele mostra que foi cadastrado. Mas se eu parar o servidor, e ver as tabelas no MySQL, a tabela sumiu.

O *persistence* está assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="nome">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>br.com.nome.model.Tabela</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="senha" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o arquivo de configuração está correto, deveria apagar quando a propriedade `hbm2ddl` fosse assim:

```
property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"
```

Talvez seja alguma configuração do banco ou do seu servidor da aplicação.
Ou você pode alterar o atributo para :

```
property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"
```

Comment: acontece quando eu paro o servidor

Comment: Estava configurado create-drop na configuração do spring mvc, troquei lá e deu certo, valeu.